# Problema com máscara no form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, script

Estou usando o plugin [Masked Input Digitalbrush](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) para formatar meu campo de telefone no formulário, tentei desta maneira e não funcionou, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<head>  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/mascara.js"></script>
</head>
```

E no `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
    $("#fone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    });
</script>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">
<form id="form" method="post" action="mail/phpmailer.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo:" name="nome">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail:" name="email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número para contato:" name="fone" id="fone">
    <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" name="msg"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use antes o Zero

```
$("#fone").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
```

Ou coloque o jquery no head e depois pode usar o

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#fone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
}
```

Comment: fiz o script no head e não funcionou, placeholder poderia influenciar nesse script?

Comment: Tem que por o jquery.js antes desse codigo. O jquery.js é que vai pra o Head. Esse pode ficar no BODY

Comment: No head:

`<script src="assets/mascara.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($){
    $("#fone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    });
 </script>`

No body: 
`<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
    $("#fone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
    });
</script>`

Comment: E tem o jquery.js antes do mascara.js?

Comment: Este: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Sim. esse mesmo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, sabe onde estou errado?

Comment: Usei um tutorial e consegui, obrigado pela ajuda! http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/mascara-para-telefones-de-8-e-9-digitos-jquery

Comment: Afinal era o quê?

Comment: segui aquele tutorial e coloquei o script dentro da tag form, dai no hover do telefone aplicou a mascara