# Criar Mascara de Telefone somente Html/Css

Tags: html, css

Teria como fazer uma mascara sem plugin em um campo do meu formulário ex: (00) 0000-0000 ?

Usand somente CSS ou HTML?

Comment: Creio que só com javascript(puro) mesmo

Comment: Ricardo, como ficaria a questão do nono digito? De qualquer forma, deve usar JavaScript.

Comment: pretendo incluir, só citei um exemplo de formatação, tenho uma pergunta em aberto tentando usar JS: [ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135478/problema-com-m%C3%A1scara-no-form ]

Comment: Fazer mascara vai dar muito trabalho de javascript puro e nada facil pode dar bug, e prefiro usar jquery chama **masked input** já ajuda, e porque não tenta? http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/3/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode usar regular expression na tag `<input>` do html5.

Não funcionará como máscara mas irá validar o telefone no formato onformado (99-99999999) ou (99-999999999).

Ex:

```
<input type="text" required id="partNumber" pattern="^[1-9]{2}\-[2-9][0-9]{7,8}$" />
```

Para o seu exemplo [(99)9999-9999] a regular expression seria `<input type="text" required id="partNumber" pattern="^\([1-9]{2}\)[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}$" />`

Veja funcionando em https://jsfiddle.net/p9at0ovL/

Obs.: Só irá funcionar nos navegadores mais novos.

Comment: Segui esse tutorial que usa a função que você citou: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/mascara-para-telefones-de-8-e-9-digitos-jquery