# HTML / CSS - input text mask date, time

Tags: html, css

Sou iniciante na area e nao tenho muito conhecimento, tenho o seguinte codigo, e gostaria que fosse prenchido apenas com numeros e no formato "00/00/0000" e "00:00" respectivamente. Sei que existem outros meios, mas gostaria de saber como fazer isso usando apenas css. E possivel?

```
<input type="text" id="txtdia" size="4px" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Dia"/>

<input type="text" id="txthora" size="4px" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Hora"/>
```

Comment: Estou apanhando ate desse programa... escrevi td mas so posta ate essa parte :/

Comment: Agora deu certo

Comment: De uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136089/criar-mascara-de-telefone-somente-html-css/136112.   Ate onde eu sei, voce não pode fazer isso com css apenas, melhor usar javascript ou qualquer outra linguagem de programação

Comment: Valeu Pena... vou ter q ver com js msm.

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript

Comment: Tem como fazer só com css sim, sou que vc precisa de um elemento dentro do input e não do placeholder default

Comment: @hugocsl... como faço isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fares eu tinha falado no comentário da possibilidade de fazer so com css, mas acredito que não vale muito a pena, pois vc teria que tirar o `placeholder` default do campo e depois colocar outro...

Então a solução que te dou e trocando o tipo do `input` no click como vc pode testar abaixo. Assim tem menos código envolvido e te da um resultado bem legal que deve te atender. Resumidamente quando vc fizer o foco no `input` ele troca o tipo de `text` para o tipo que vc definir `onfocus="(this.type='time')"` etc e quando vc clica fora ele volta pro `text`

```css
input {
    width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtdia" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Dia" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"/>

    <input type="text" id="txthora" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Hora" onfocus="(this.type='time')" onblur="(this.type='text')"/>
```

Comment: Olha q bacana.... gostei

Answer (score 3):

De forma alternativa, você também pode utilizar os novos tipos de inputs do HTML5, que são os do tipo `date` e `time`.

Sua sintaxe seria:

`<input id="date" type="date">`

`<input id="time" type="time">`

```css
.datetime {
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 200px;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="time" class="datetime" type="time">
<input id="date" class="datetime" type="date">
```

Como referência, segue dois links caso queira saber mais!

[Input Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

[Input Time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Comment: Victor Jordan... tmb ja tentei com esses tipos, mas são muito chatos pra editar, nao consegui ajustar width height, queria tirar tmb a seta que aparece o calendario, tmb não consegui colocar um placeholder, etc...

Comment: @fares Os ajustes de layout são facilmente aplicados através de classes ou passando a propriedade diretamente bem como a seta dos calendários. Alterei o código para exemplificar. O que realmente não teria como fazer seria aplicar o placeholder :(

Comment: Tem o codigo alterado pra dar uma olhada